# how to add two view in single super()?

Tags: android

am working on my first project, i want to use single recyclerview adapter to show two recycler view in two different activity, but app crash after i start second activity(when first recyclerview item is clicked) i got this error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> com.example.smschecker.adapters.KoreaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()'
> on a null object reference
> at com.example.smschecker.SeasonDetails$1.onDataChange(SeasonDetails.java:137)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)

I know the error meaning, but i cant overcome

In Adapter,

```
 @NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.korea_item,parent,false);
    View itemView3 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.details_season_item, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView, itemView3);
}
```

public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, View itemView3) {
super(itemView);

```
        SmsAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.koreaTitle);
        KoreaImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.korea_image);
        progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progres_bar_korea);
        seasonNumber = itemView2.findViewById(R.id.season_number);
```

// here is where error originate, because at super(itemView), itemView3 cant be shown in secont activity, i was thinking of this `super(itemView, itemView3)` its not working, i want itemView3 in second Activity

Comment: "how to add two view in single super()?" -- you don't. "i want to use single recyclerview adapter to show two recycler view in two different activity" -- while you can use a single adapter *class* in two different activity *classes*, you can only use a single adapter *object* in a single activity *object*. So, an adapter object is either attached to an instance of the first activity or the second activity, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can achieve it by this way**

Firstly Add 3 Integer variables in your Model class name `type` ITEM_TYPE_1 and
ITEM_TYPE_2. Assign a value to `type` According to your need. like ITEM_TYPE_1 or ITEM_TYPE_2 respectively for view type 1 and view type 2.

```
public class Model{
        String SmsAddress;
        String KoreaImage;
        String seasonNumber;
        Integer type;
        public  static final Integer ITEM_TYPE_1=1;
        public  static final Integer ITEM_TYPE_2=2;

        public String getSmsAddress() {
            return SmsAddress;
        }

        public void setSmsAddress(String smsAddress) {
            SmsAddress = smsAddress;
        }

        public String getKoreaImage() {
            return KoreaImage;
        }

        public void setKoreaImage(String koreaImage) {
            KoreaImage = koreaImage;
        }

        public String getSeasonNumber() {
            return seasonNumber;
        }

        public void setSeasonNumber(String seasonNumber) {
            this.seasonNumber = seasonNumber;
        }

        public Integer getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(Integer type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
```

> At your Adapter you can override `getItemViewType()` and `onCreateViewHolder`() methods and apply a switch case for view inflation and Data Presentation through ViewHolders.

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        switch (modelList.get(position).getType()) {
            case 0:
                return Model.ITEM_TYPE_1;
            case 1:
                return Model.ITEM_TYPE_2;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    switch (viewType) {
        case Model.ITEM_TYPE_1:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_type_1, parent, false);
            return (new Item1ViewHolder(view));

        case Model.ITEM_TYPE_2:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_type_2, parent, false);
            return (new Item2ViewHolder(view));
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```