# Adding multiple different CardViews to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a `RecyclerView` and I want to add to that `RecyclerView` multiple different `CardViews`.
Lets say I have `cardview1.xml`, `cardview2.xml`, `cardview3.xml`
each `ViewCard` has Class that have the `variables` for the `ViewCard`and the Classes extends from Class called CardView that I created with no properties.

I want to add to one `RecyclerView` 3 `cardview1`, 2 `cardview2`, 4 `cardview3`.

I want to know how to do that in My `Adapter`

CardView1:

```
public class CardView1 extends CardView {

    public CardView1(){

    }

}
```

CardView2:

```
public class CardView2 extends CardView {

    public CardView2(){

    }
}
```

CardView3:

```
public class CardView3 extends CardView {
    private String number;

    public CardView3(String number){
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

}
```

If you need me to add any code please tell.

Comment: Hi Yaniv. Here is a good [**tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VtnLpHUu2U0). I am sure it willl help

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an ArrayList to your Adapter.
This ArrayList represent a list of your data.
In your adapter you have just to know with getType() which cardView to show.
So for example :

```
YourAdapter(datas ArrayList<YourData>(),...){
onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int){
     val type = getItemViewType(position)
     if(type == 0){
        //show cardview1
         YourViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.cardview1, parent, false))
     }
     if(type == 1){
          YourViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.cardview2, parent, false))
     }

}
@override
public Int getItemViewType(int position){
            
            
            return datas[position].type;
             
        }
}
```

After YourData has to have a method type ( for this example).
And you can add 3 elements of type 0 , after 2 elements of type 1 ... in the arraylist.

Sorry because there's a mix between kotlin and Java ( but I think you can understand)

Answer (score 0):

**You can achieve it by this way**

Firstly Add 3 Integer variables in your Model class name `type` ITEM_TYPE_1 and
ITEM_TYPE_2. Assign a value to `type` According to your need. like ITEM_TYPE_1 or ITEM_TYPE_2 respectively for view type 1 and view type 2.

```
public class Model{
        String SmsAddress;
        String KoreaImage;
        String seasonNumber;
        Integer type;
        public  static final Integer ITEM_TYPE_1=1;
        public  static final Integer ITEM_TYPE_2=2;

        public String getSmsAddress() {
            return SmsAddress;
        }

        public void setSmsAddress(String smsAddress) {
            SmsAddress = smsAddress;
        }

        public String getKoreaImage() {
            return KoreaImage;
        }

        public void setKoreaImage(String koreaImage) {
            KoreaImage = koreaImage;
        }

        public String getSeasonNumber() {
            return seasonNumber;
        }

        public void setSeasonNumber(String seasonNumber) {
            this.seasonNumber = seasonNumber;
        }

        public Integer getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(Integer type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
```

> At your Adapter you can override `getItemViewType()` and `onCreateViewHolder`() methods and apply a switch case for view inflation and Data Presentation through ViewHolders.

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        switch (modelList.get(position).getType()) {
            case 0:
                return Model.ITEM_TYPE_1;
            case 1:
                return Model.ITEM_TYPE_2;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    switch (viewType) {
        case Model.ITEM_TYPE_1:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_type_1, parent, false);
            return (new Item1ViewHolder(view));

        case Model.ITEM_TYPE_2:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_type_2, parent, false);
            return (new Item2ViewHolder(view));
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

For More Detail see the link below:

[See Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64388849/how-to-add-two-view-in-single-super/64390039#64390039)

Comment: Make constant variables in a class to compare and Assign a value.